# Unable to run MySQL database migrations after updating from .NET Core 1.x to 2.x, Unknown database ' '

Tags: mysql, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have recently tried updating a working .NET Core 1.0 project using MySQL to .NET Core 2.0. I followed the instructions in Microsoft's documentation and got it to compile and run but I am completely unable to perform database migrations. Whenever I try to run Update-Database from the Package Manager console I end up with an error saying:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'user' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database '')
```

My problem is that even though the username and connection are properly taken from the connection string, the database name isn't. I even connected to the database from the Server Explorer window using the very same information from the connection string; and I checked the correct appsettings (Development) file was the one in use.

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;database=asm;userid=user;password=password;connectionreset=true;Allow User Variables=True"
  },
```

I googled the error message but only found posts and comments where the database name had a typo or plainly didn't exist, but this is not the case. The database user has all administrative roles and privileges set in MySQL Workbench.
Any help or pointers (even how to debug the Update-Database process to inspect when the DbContext is created/set) will be much appreciated.

**Added info:**

*Startup.cs (redacted to omit some usings and most services.AddScoped<>())*

```
using asm.Data;
using asm.Enumeration;
using asm.Models;
using asm.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Serilog;

namespace asm
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            // Add Options
            services.AddOptions();

            services.Configure<Options>(Configuration.GetSection("Properties"));

            services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("/opt/app/key/"))
                .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90));


            //Add MVC properties
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization()
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
            services.AddScoped<ILanguageActionFilter, LanguageActionFilter>();
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                options =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("es-AR"),
                        new CultureInfo("es"),
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("en")
                    };
                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "es-AR", uiCulture: "es-AR");
                    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                });


            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("asm"))
            );

            services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityErrorDescriber, Services.Security.IdentityErrorDescriber>();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Role>((opt) =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                opt.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                opt.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            //Add Memory Cache
            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options => { options.CookieName = ".cookie.name"; options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40); });

            // Security
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("User Register", policy => policy.RequireClaim("UserRegister"));
                options.AddPolicy("Portal Policy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("PortalClaim"));
            });

            #region GlobalIsoDependencies

            // Redacted: Lots of services like: 
            // services.AddScoped<ThingRepository, ThingRepository>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseSession();

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }

    }
}
```

*ApplicationDbContext.cs (Redacted too):*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using crm.Models;
using crm.Models.GlobalIso;
using crm.Models.EmailMarketing;
using crm.Models.Idomum;
using crm.Models.Integrations.Mercadopago;
using crm.Models.GlobalIso.MA;
using crm.Models.GlobalIso.Type;
using crm.Models.GlobalIso.RT;
using crm.Models.GlobalIso.Maintenance;
using crm.Models.Crm;

namespace asm.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            // Redacted: Lots of:
            // builder.Entity<>(ClassName).ToTable("TABLE_NAME");

            builder.Entity<Profile>().ToTable("ROLE_PROFILE");
            builder.Entity<UserProfile>().ToTable("ROLE_PROFILE_USER");
            builder.Entity<ProfileRole>().ToTable("ROLE_PROFILE_ROLE");

            String longtext = "LONGTEXT";

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Enterprise)
            .WithMany(e => e.ApplicationUserList);

            builder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Application);

            builder.Entity<UserProfile>()
                .HasKey(up => new { up.ApplicationUserID, up.ProfileID });

            builder.Entity<UserProfile>()
                .HasOne(up => up.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(u => u.UserProfileList)
                .HasForeignKey(up => up.ApplicationUserID);

            builder.Entity<UserProfile>()
                .HasOne(up => up.Profile)
                .WithMany(p => p.UserProfileList)
                .HasForeignKey(up => up.ProfileID);

            builder.Entity<ProfileRole>()
                .HasKey(pr => new { pr.RoleID, pr.ProfileID });

            //TODO: The key {'RoleID'} contains properties in shadow state and is referenced by a relationship from 'Role.PerfileRoleList' to 'PerfileRole.Role'.
            //Configure a non-shadow principal key for this relationship.
            builder.Entity<ProfileRole>()
                .HasOne(pr => pr.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.ProfileRoleList)
                .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.RoleID);


            builder.Entity<ProfileRole>()
                .HasOne(pr => pr.Profile)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProfileRoleList)
                .HasForeignKey(pr => pr.ProfileID);


            builder.Entity<Enterprise>()
                .HasOne(tc => tc.Enterprise_Parent)
                .WithMany(p => p.EnterpriseChildList)
                .HasForeignKey(tc => tc.Enterprise_ParentID);

            builder.Entity<UserEnterprise>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.ApplicationUserID, t.EnterpriseID });

            builder.Entity<UserEnterprise>()
                .HasOne(ue => ue.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(p => p.UserEnterpriseList)
                .HasForeignKey(tc => tc.ApplicationUserID);

            builder.Entity<UserEnterprise>()
                .HasOne(ue => ue.Enterprise)
                .WithMany(p => p.UserEnterpriseList)
                .HasForeignKey(tc => tc.EnterpriseID);
        }

        public DbSet<Enterprise> Enterprise { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserEnterprise> UserEnterprise { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Application> Application { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ApplicationEnterprise> ApplicationEnterprise { get; set; }


        // Many to Many Relations
        public DbSet<UserSettings> UserSettings { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Profile> Profile { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProfileRole> ProfileRole { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfile { get; set; }


    }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using asm.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace asm
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    SeedData.Initialize(services).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
                }

            }
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Share your startup code and db context class.

Comment: @MarkG Added. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the latest version (8.0.11) of MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore?

Comment: What is your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable set to?

Comment: @MarkG MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore version is 8.0.11 in .csproj file; and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is "Development" in launchSettings.json

Comment: Maybe override [OnConfiguring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#onconfiguring) and inspect/change the connection string.